# StackOverFlowException thrown and process terminated #253

Tags: .net, node.js, edge.js

I'm not sure this is the issue from Edgejs, I just hope anyone meet the same issue with this, and give some suggestions how to figure out the reason. anyway, 'process is terminated due to StackOverflowException' should be happened from .net runtime, right?

image

My Nodejs codes are tcp server, whenever data received, it will call the .net code and the .net code is just responsible for storing data in sql server.
Nodejs code which define the edge function as below:

```
module.exports.updateStation = edge.func({
assemblyFile: clrAssembly,
typeName: clrType,
methodName: 'UpdateStationAsync'
```

});

below is the .net code for the updateStation function:

```
public async Task<object> UpdateStationAsync(dynamic station)
{
    string projid = (string)station.projid;
    string stid = (string)station.stid;
    using (var context = new FlyDataContext(ConnectString))
    {
        var st = await context.Stations.FirstOrDefaultAsync(
            s => s.ProjectID == projid && s.StationID == stid);
        if (st != null)
        {
            st.IpAddress = (string)station.ip;
            st.IpPort = (int)station.port;
            st.ServerPort = (int)station.serverport;
            st.LastCmd = (string)station.cmd;
            st.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
        }
        else
        {
            st = new Station()
            {
                ProjectID = projid,
                StationID = stid,
                IpAddress = (string)station.ip,
                IpPort = (int)station.port,
                ServerPort = (int)station.serverport,
                Interval = 10,
                LastCmd = (string)station.cmd,
                LastUpdated = DateTime.Now
            };
            context.Stations.Add(st);
        }

        return await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

ConnectString is read from config file of the Dll, like below:

```
   private static string _connString = null;
protected static string ConnectString
{
    get
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_connString))
        {
            string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
            UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
            string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
            string configpath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(path), "Fly.Data.dll.config");
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(configpath);
            XElement root = doc.Root;
            _connString = (from e in root.Element("connectionStrings").Elements("add")
                           where e.Attribute("name").Value == "FlyDataContext"
                           select e.Attribute("connectionString").Value).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        return _connString;
    }
}
```

I just use Entity Framework to access sql server, not more complex codes there. I'm confused that I looked through my codes, didn't find any recursion calling.

And the point is StachOverflowException happens after the program running for a while, not always occurred at the same place or same time, it 's so strange to me, looks like it is random, but exception always happen after a while, it is about no more than 1 minute.

Comment: additional info: I'm using NodeJs to develop a Tcp server, and whenever new message comes, I will handle this message to store it in MS Sql server. So I involved the EdgeJs, which can call .NET code in Nodejs, I implemented .NET code in assembly (.dll).

Comment: After the prpogram run for a while (there are nearly 20 ~ 40 tcp clients connected, and send message to this server), no more than one minute, I will get the StackOverflowException which terminated the whole process. this is strange, I guess this exception should be thrown by the .NET runtime, right? but I didn't find anywhere will cause the stack overflow (no any recursion call there). Has any one meet this before?